# how to set certain bucket in Firebase Storage using admin SDK?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

if using default bucket, I can use code like this:

```
const storage = admin.storage()
const defaultBucket = storage.bucket()
const thumbnailFile = defaultBucket.file(`eventThumbnail/${creatorID}/${eventID}`)
```

but now I have set a new bucket with certain name ("gs://newBucketNameHere"), so what is the code to make a reference to a new storage bucket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the name of the bucket to the [`bucket()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html#bucket) method, but without the `gs://` "protocol" part.

```
const newBucket = storage.bucket("newBucketNameHere")
const thumbnailFile = newBucket.file(`eventThumbnail/${creatorID}/${eventID}`)
```